# Importing class from module but functions not working

Tags: python, python-import

I created two programs, one is an ATM simulator and other is a Virtual Doctor which reads data from excel sheet and on the basis of user input, tells what disease the user might be suffering from.

now I want to connect the atm to virtual doctor such that it withdraws the amount of medicines from the bank account

I imported atm to virtual doctor but the functions don't seem to be working, they do nothing when called and the process exits.

```
#code for ATM
userpin = ["1234", "2345", "3456", "4567"]
userpass = ["1234", "2345", "3456", "4567"]
username = ["Rishabh", "Siddharth", "Kashish", "Mahima"]
userbalance = [20500, 43567, 45672, 67800]

class Bank:

    def __init__(self, bal=0, index=0):
        #if __name__ == '__main__':
            self.bal = bal
            self.index = index

    def start(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            print("\t\t=== Welcome to ATM ===")

            inputpin=input("Enter your pin :")
            inputpass= input("Enter your password :")
            b1.pinpasscheck(inputpin,inputpass)

    def pinpasscheck(self,pin,passw):
        self.pin=pin
        self.passw=passw
        inputpin=pin
        inputpass=passw
        index=0
        flag= False
        for i in range(0,len(userpin)):
            if inputpin==userpin[i]:
                index=i
                print(index)
                if inputpass==userpass[index]:
                    print("Login Succeeded !")
                    flag= True
                    b1.operationlist(index)
                    if flag==False:
                        print("Login invalid. Please check username or password")
                    else:
                        pass
                else:
                    pass

    def operationlist(self,indexval):

        self.indexval=indexval
        index=indexval
        print("\n Hello, ", username[index])
        print("""
                    1)        Balance
                    2)        Withdraw
                    3)        Deposit
                    4)        Change password
                    5)        Quit
                    """)
        useroption = int(input("Select an option:"))

        if useroption == 1:
            print("\nYour current balance is {}".format(userbalance[index]))
            b1.operationlist(index)

        elif useroption == 2:
            amount= int(input("\nEnter amount you want you want to withdraw : Rs"))
            b1.withdraw(amount,index)

        else:
            print("None of the above options selected. Please select any one of the provided options.")
            b1.operationlist(index)

    def withdraw(self, amt, index):
        self.amt= amt
        amount = amt
        self.index= index
        if amount > userbalance[index]:
            print("Oops! Insufficient funds.")
            b1.operationlist(index)

        rembalance = userbalance[index] - amount
        userbalance.remove(userbalance[index])
        userbalance.insert(index, rembalance)
        print("Your remaining balance is: ", userbalance[index])
        b1.operationlist(index)

b1 = Bank()
b1.start()
```

---

```
#code for VirtualDoctor
import xlrd
import pandas
from NewATM import Bank

path = "symptoms.xlsx"
book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
sheet= book.sheet_by_index(0)
b2= Bank()

data= [[sheet.cell_value(r,c) for c in range (sheet.ncols)] for r in range (sheet.nrows)]

diseaselist= []
for i in range (1,sheet.nrows):
    diseaselist.append(sheet.cell_value(i,0))

symptoms=[]
for i in range (1, data.__len__()):
    tmp= data[i][1:5]
    symptoms.append(tmp)

print(symptoms)
inputlist = []
b2.start() #THIS DOES NOT WORKK !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! WHY ???
```

The virtual doctor program should now go to the atm and then I can move forward with my code, but this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Where are you getting problem

Comment: the start function(of the atm) doesn't work when called in the Doctor program

Comment: I can call other functions but not the start function. Why so ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the code from your ATM class requires data which is set as global variables in the class itself. In terms of OOP, this is bad practice and in your particular case the code just won’t work as the variables are out of scope to the main (virtual doctor).

Either move those variables into the class itself (which is still bad practice) or keep them elsewhere and import the matrix of data when calling the class, and pass it to each individual functions.

Lastly you are creating an instance of bank called b1 to use in the class, which doesn’t make sense in terms of OOP. Change the b1 to self such that your calling the functions like self.function (one edit is changing b1.pinpasscheck() to self.pinpasscheck()).